# My like/dislike system not working as expected php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to create a like/dislike system so a user can rate a video. However, I've been stuck on an issue for some time. The like button doesn't update the MySQL Table when clicked.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

if( !empty( $_GET['$v_id'] ) ){

    $vid = $_SESSION['v_id'] = $_GET['$v_id'];

 $sql='SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id=?';
    $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $vid );
    $res=$stmt->execute();
    if( $res ){
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $videoname );
        $stmt->fetch();

        printf('
            <video width="70%%" height="70%%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
                <source src="uploads/%s" type="video/mp4" id="vid">
            </video>
        ', $videoname );
    }
} else {
    exit('missing ID');
}

$likeQuery = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT likes FROM video WHERE v_id='$vid'");
$likeCount = 0;
$func = <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
function like(event){

alert( '$likeCount' = 1 );
}

function dislike(event){

    alert( '$likeCount' = -1 );
}
</script>
EOD;
if($likeCount == 1){
 mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE video SET likes = likes + 1 
            WHERE (v_id = '$vid')");} elseif($likeCount == -1){
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE video SET likes = likes - 1 
            WHERE (v_id = '$vid')");}
?>


<br>
<a href="#" onclick="like(event)"><img src="imageStoring/like.png" style="height:30px;" /></a>
<img src="imageStoring/dislike.png" style="height:30px;"/>
```

I added the code that displays the video because I'm not sure if that's causing the issue.

below is the mySQL code,

```
CREATE TABLE video(
v_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
video_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY user_id(id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
n_views INT,
likes INT,
dislikes INT,
image_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NILL
);
```

I tried editing it before by using,

```
href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"
```

However I kept getting 'missing ID'.

Comment: Does your url look like this `/?$v_id=123` or `/?v_id=123`. If so, try to change `$_GET['$v_id']` in `$_GET['v_id']`

Comment: I tried what you said, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You can't mix client and server side code like that.  When a button is clicked in javascript the only way to make PHP do something is to send a http request to the server.

Comment: side note: you've randomly used prepared statements and parameters for one SQL query, but not for the second one, leaving it potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Make sure you always use parameterisation consistently.

Comment: +ADyson Thanks, I almost missed that.

Comment: @DanielBarbosadosSantos see my answer for a detailed implementation

Answer (score 1):

When you click the like button, it's happening via javascript which is already loaded onto the client's browser.

The php parsing occurs on the server end, before it reaches your client's browser.

You'd need to have a route in your php server listening for a valid like request, preferably from a registered user like so:

```
POST localhost/api/video/rating/:vote
```

Where the parameter "vote" is an integer value.

On the php side for that route, parse the parameter value, connect to your table, update the video's total vote, and return a success status.

On the front end for your javascript, change your code to the following:

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
        var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
                function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
            ).join('&');

        var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.open('POST', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(params);
        return xhr;
    }

    // example upvote request
    postAjax('localhost/api/video/rating', 'vote=1', function(data){ console.log(data); });

    // example downvote request
    postAjax('localhost/api/video/rating', 'vote=-1', function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Replace the upvote and downvote buttons with both respective examples

Comment: Sorry for replying late; I just tried your code and it still leaves the likes/dislikes columns at zero after clicking the buttons.

Comment: Did you add the route? I you'll have to supply the backend code for the route yourself.

Comment: I'm still a little new to php; would this, ('localhost/VarcFiles/watchScreen.php?$v_id=\'$vid\' '), be an example of a rout?

Comment: generally speaking, if thats what you type at the top of your url to access it then yes

Comment: I placed postAjax('localhost/VarcFiles/watchScreen.php?$v_id=\'$vid\'', 'vote=-1', function(data){ console.log(data); }); in the onclick like you said in your answer, however I'm still confused as to where I would place; $_POST('localhost/VarcFiles/watchScreen.php?$v_id=\'$vid\'/:vote'). I tried placing it as a link in href="" however I get an Object not found! error

Comment: It's clear you're a beginner. You need to read up on writing PHP scripts and using GET/POST requests from javascript. Once you have a grasp how they're supposed to connect, you can come back and understand my tutorial better and you'll have it working in no time.